# while loop to iterate and duplicate rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Date From': ['2023-03-01', '2023-01-01'], 
                       'Date To': ['2023-06-01', '2023-02-28']
                     })
    df['Date From'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date From'])
    df['Date To'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date To'])
    df['Date End'] = df['Date From'] + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    df['Date End'] = pd.to_detatime(df['Date End'])
```

I am trying to duplicate the rows using a while loop:

```
    while df['Date End'].iloc[-1] < df['Date To'].iloc[0]:
        new_row = {'Date From': df['Date End'].iloc[-1] + datetime.timedelta(days=1),
                   'Date End': df['Date End'].iloc[-1] + datetime.timedelta(days=7),
                   'Date To': df['Date To'].iloc[0]
                  }
        df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

However, this while loop only works if there is 1 element in the dataframe. I have tried to create an ID column and used a groupby but the groupby function does not work with append or iloc.

The final dataframe should look something like this:

```
|Date From|       |Date End}|       |Date To|
-----------       ------------      ---------
|2023-03-01|      |2023-03-08|      |2023-06-01|
|2023-03-09|      |2023-03-15|      |2023-06-01|
|2023-03-16|      |2023-03-22|      |2023-06-01|
|...       |      |...       |      |...       |
|2023-01-01|      |2023-01-08|      |2023-02-28|
|2023-01-09|      |2023-01-15|      |2023-02-28|
|2023-01-16|      |2023-01-22|      |2023-02-28|
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing comes from the `df.append` inside your loop. First of all, it is inneficient. What you can do instead is th iterate over each row:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


df = pd.DataFrame({'Date From': ['2023-03-01', '2023-01-01'], 
                   'Date To': ['2023-06-01', '2023-02-28']
                  })
df['Date From'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date From'])
df['Date To'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date To'])
df['Date End'] = df['Date From'] + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

new_rows = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    current_date_from = row['Date From']
    date_to = row['Date To']
    while current_date_from + datetime.timedelta(days=7) <= date_to:
        new_date_from = current_date_from + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        new_date_end = new_date_from + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        if new_date_end > date_to:
            new_date_end = date_to
        new_rows.append({'Date From': new_date_from, 'Date To': date_to, 'Date End': new_date_end})
        current_date_from = new_date_from

new_rows_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)
final_df = pd.concat([df, new_rows_df], ignore_index=True)

final_df = final_df.sort_values(by='Date From').reset_index(drop=True)

print(final_df)
```

which returns:

```
0  2023-01-01 2023-02-28 2023-01-08
1  2023-01-08 2023-02-28 2023-01-15
2  2023-01-15 2023-02-28 2023-01-22
3  2023-01-22 2023-02-28 2023-01-29
4  2023-01-29 2023-02-28 2023-02-05
5  2023-02-05 2023-02-28 2023-02-12
6  2023-02-12 2023-02-28 2023-02-19
7  2023-02-19 2023-02-28 2023-02-26
8  2023-02-26 2023-02-28 2023-02-28
9  2023-03-01 2023-06-01 2023-03-08
10 2023-03-08 2023-06-01 2023-03-15
11 2023-03-15 2023-06-01 2023-03-22
12 2023-03-22 2023-06-01 2023-03-29
13 2023-03-29 2023-06-01 2023-04-05
14 2023-04-05 2023-06-01 2023-04-12
15 2023-04-12 2023-06-01 2023-04-19
16 2023-04-19 2023-06-01 2023-04-26
17 2023-04-26 2023-06-01 2023-05-03
18 2023-05-03 2023-06-01 2023-05-10
19 2023-05-10 2023-06-01 2023-05-17
20 2023-05-17 2023-06-01 2023-05-24
21 2023-05-24 2023-06-01 2023-05-31
22 2023-05-31 2023-06-01 2023-06-01
```